# The characteristic function of the Cantor set is Riemann integrable

Tags: lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

Show that $X_C(x)$ is Riemann integrable over [0,1] where $C\subset [0,1]$ is Cantor set annd find $\int$ $X_c(x)dx$ (from 0 to 1)

Guys could you help me about this question?

Comment: Is it the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)?

Comment: It would help to know what you can use. Do we have to prove it from the definition of the Riemann integral? Or, seeing as you used the Lebesgue measure tag, can we use the characterization of Riemann integrable functions as bounded and having measure zero set of discontinuities?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Split the interval $[0,1]$ into $3^n$ equal subintervals. A subinterval is *bad* if it contains points of $C$ in its interior. Count the bad intervals $B_k$! Replace each  $B_k$ by $B_k'$, where $B_k'$ is obtained by stretching $B_k$  from its center by a factor $1+\epsilon$, $\epsilon\ll1$. The $B_k'$ and the remaining spaces $S_k$ between successive $B_k'$ form a partition ${\cal P}$ of $[0,1]$. Now estimate the upper sum belonging to ${\cal P}$, using that on the $S_k$ the characteristic function of $C$ is $\equiv0$.